# How to create a default profile and launch outlook client(GUI) using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I was trying to launch Outlook with default profile or create default profile  using  **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook** assembly file. but i'm getting following error while launch my outlook application. 
Error message: **The property "http: //schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7C070102" is unknown or can not be found**. 
And i'm new to this assembly. Also suggest any other framework to achieve my goal

```
 Outlook.Application OutlookClient()
    {
        Outlook.Application oOutlook = null;
        Outlook.NameSpace oNS = null;
        oOutlook = new Outlook.Application();
        oNS = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        oNS.Logon("My profile", "myprofilepassword", false, false);
        oOutlook = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
        return oOutlook;
    }
```

Comment: And which line throws the error?

Comment: The property error must be coming from PropertyAccessor.GetProperty, not from the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no need to initialize the Application instance object twice in the code:

```
oOutlook = new Outlook.Application();
```

and

```
oOutlook = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
```

Second, there is no need to use the `Logon` method.

Here is what MSDN states for that:

> Use the Logon method only to log on to a specific profile when Outlook is not already running. This is because only one Outlook process can run at a time, and that Outlook process uses only one profile and supports only one MAPI session. When users start Outlook a second time, that instance of Outlook runs within the same Outlook process, does not create a new process, and uses the same profile.
>
> If Outlook is already running, using this method does not create a new Outlook session or change the current profile to a different one.
>
> If Outlook is not running and you only want to start Outlook with the default profile, do not use the Logon method. A better alternative is shown in the following code example, InitializeMAPI: first, instantiate the Outlook Application object, then reference a default folder such as the Inbox. This has the side effect of initializing MAPI to use the default profile and to make the object model fully functional.

```
Sub InitializeMAPI ()

  ' Start Outlook.
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

  ' Get a session object. 
  Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
  Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

  ' Create an instance of the Inbox folder. 
  ' If Outlook is not already running, this has the side
  ' effect of initializing MAPI.
  Dim mailFolder As Outlook.Folder
  Set mailFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

  ' Continue to use the object model to automate Outlook.
End Sub
```

Starting in Outlook 2010, if you have multiple profiles, you have configured Outlook to always use a default profile, and you use the `Logon` method to log on to the default profile without prompting the user, the user will receive a prompt to choose a profile anyway. To avoid this behavior, do not use the `Logon` method; use the workaround suggested in the preceding `InitializeMAPI` example instead.

So, your code should look like the following one:

```
Outlook.Application OutlookClient()
{
    Outlook.Application oOutlook = null;
    Outlook.NameSpace oNS = null;
    oOutlook = new Outlook.Application();

    // optional
    oNS = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    Outlook.MAPIFolder folderInbox = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    return oOutlook;
}
```

See the [C# app automates Outlook (CSAutomateOutlook)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomateOutlook-a3b7bdc9) sample code.

Comment: Hi Eugene, 
Thanks a lot for your information. just need a clarification here for one more scenario, what if outlook doesn't have a default profile which outlook is freshly installed and doesn't configured with any Microsoft account. How to overcome this one ?

Comment: The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for configuring mail profiles.